# Custom animation for loading data

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, uiviewpropertyanimator

Here I have been trying so long to create a custom animated progress bar.

I'm trying to move a view from screen's one end to second end with resizing.

view's frmae is (0, 100, 10, 4)

What I want is...

- At start of animation view should be at its initial position, lets say at (0, 100)
- in the middle of the animation view will be at the middle of the screen and its width will be increased to 100px.
- at the end of the animation view will be at screen's second end. and frame of the view will be at, lets say (400, 100) and width off the view will be again back to 10px
- The whole progress should be reversed also.

**UIButton Action method**

```
var mainView = UIView() 

@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 10, height: 4)
    mainView = UIView(frame: rect)
    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(mainView)

    animate()
}
```

**Animation Method**

```
func animate() {


    let theAnimationTranslationX = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    theAnimationTranslationX.fromValue      = mainView.bounds.minX
    theAnimationTranslationX.toValue        = 400

    let scaleAnimate:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.x")
    scaleAnimate.fromValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1))
    scaleAnimate.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 0, 0))


    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.autoreverses = true
    group.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    group.animations = [theAnimationTranslationX]//, scaleAnimate]
    group.duration = 2
    group.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    mainView.layer.add(group, forKey: "animation")
}
```

I'm not getting the desired animation effect.

Is there any other way to do so or is it possible with any other way please suggest me.

Thanks for you time and any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The final animation should look like...

[image]

Comment: @matt, please check qus. I edited and added animation image.

Comment: Please checkout this playground, it's a circle but it get's around the same effect
https://github.com/alinekborges/PlaygroundPropertyAnimator